# Clickthrough container div with overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a full-screen map web app with a list of items at the bottom. The idea is user can scroll up the list, like many native mobile apps.

[This is what I'm trying to do. (GIF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvWZ9.gif)

I don't know how to make this. I make scroll container `'pointer-events: none;'`. This makes back map clickable, but scroll doesn't work. It would be perfect a `pointer-events: onlyscroll` :), but this not exists.

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="general">
  <div id="full_screen_map">
    HERE IS THE MAP
  </div>
  <div id="full_screen_scroll_container">
    <div id="content">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#general{
  #full_screen_map{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  }
  #full_screen_scroll_container{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    #content{
      margin-top: 300px;
    }
  }
}
```

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tonicastillo/q9sa2yeh/41/

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: This is not a thing where pointer-events should come into play at all; rather you should stop placing two elements that take the full available viewport on top of each other in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. This is a good idea. But I don't know how to expand the scroll container area in touch move event.

Comment: @PrashanthOlekar Thanks. Which Bootstrap component do that?

Comment: try to use `z-index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to put the map inside the scroller area.

```
<div id="fixed_full_screen_scroll_container">
  <div id="fixed_full_screen_map">
    FIXED MAP
  </div>
  <div id="content_with_top_Xpx">
    CONTENT WITH SCROLL
  </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9sa2yeh/58/

This works in mobile touch screen and mouse scroll wheel only in content area, and the map is clickable/graggable/etc...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for. I slightly changed the css. Please take a look

```
#general{
  #full_screen_map{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  }
  #full_screen_scroll_container{
    position: relative; /* here I removed fixed position */
    z-index: 1;
    top: 300px; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; /* added top position and removed margin */
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is not the perfect solution, but this give me an idea. In your example you are using document scroll. I can't do this in my project. But I think the solution is to put the map inside scrolled container as fixed element.

Comment: Yes that should do it :)